# How many specific value exist in a string array in android

Tags: android

I have a string array like this :

```
String[] sample = { "0", "1", "0", "5", "1", "0" };
```

now i need to know how many specific value like 0 exist in this array.
so how can i get that?

Comment: Are you trying to count the number of unique values in an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this may help you..

```
    int count = 0;
    String[] array = new String[]{"a", "a", "d", "c", "d", "c", "v"};
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(array));
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        count = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < arrayList.size(); j++) {
            if (arrayList.get(j).equals(array[i])) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Occurance of " + array[i] + " in Array is : " + count);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

try  `HashMap` to keep track of occurrences of each word in array.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] sample = { "0", "1", "0", "5", "1", "0" };
         Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
            for (String s : sample) {
                Integer n = map.get(s);
                n = (n == null) ? 1 : ++n;
                map.put(s,n);
            }

            System.out.println(map);

    }
```

output:(hope this is what you want)

```
{1=2, 0=3, 5=1}
```

for iterating map use:

```
   Iterator it = map.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " occurs = " +      pair.getValue()+" times");

    }
```

output:

```
1 occurs = 2 times
0 occurs = 3 times
5 occurs = 1 times
```